# logback FileAppender Unsynchronized?

Tags: java, logging, synchronization, logback

If you look at FileAppender in logback, you will see OutputStreamAppender -> UnsynchronizedAppenderBase

It doesn't seem to be syncing.

Is what I thought correct?

Or is it synchronized somewhere else?

Comment: Does https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-core/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/core/OutputStreamAppender.java#L196 answer your question? If not, please me more explicit about what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: @kdgregory streamWriteLock.lock();

Are you synchronizing the log file when you write it?

My problem is that when multiple threads write to a single log file in JSON format, the JSON format is broken and entered in a jumbled manner due to concurrency issues.

Comment: That will single-thread output for the appender. It won't protect against multiple appenders writing to the same file, or multiple programs. If you aren't doing these things, then you'll need to edit your question with a minimal reproducible example to provide more information (including your build script with dependencies).

Comment: @kdgregory Thanks for the reply.

This is the link I asked a question about previously.

Could this be of help to you?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77750869/simultaneous-logging-to-a-single-file-causing-log-corruption-in-logback

Comment: If the logging configuration in that question is the correct configuration, then it means that you're generating the JSON before calling the logger. Which implies that the corruption is happening in whatever code generates that JSON, not the logging library.